# The text of the Label not changing in Java

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, jlabel, event-dispatch-thread

Im creating a UI for my project and that involves JLabel (javax.swing) which needs to update the text (of the Label) everytime that task is done.

I use label.setText to change/update the text inside (like the one shown below.) However, most of the time, the label doesnt change the text. I tried to use label.UpdateUI() hoping that it will solve the problem, but it doesnt.

```
taskLabel.setText(msg);
```

Any ideas?

```
if (gatherSamplesValue)
{
      if (SourceACheckBox)
      {
           try 
           { 
                Thread setLabelText1 = new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        taskLabel.setText(msg);

                    taskLabel.validate();
                }
             };
             msg = "Task : Gathering URLs from Phish Tank. DateTime: " + Main.getCurrentDate();
             setLabelText1.start();
             SourceA.sourceAMain();
             msg="Done with the task : " + Main.getCurrentDate();
             Thread setLabelText2 = new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    taskLabel.setText(msg);
                    taskLabel.validate();
                }
             };
             setLabelText2.start();
      } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
 }

 if (SourceBCheckBox)
 {
  .
  .
 }

 if (SourceCCheckBox)
 {
  .
  .
 }
```

}

Here's the code, imagine that I nee to put the same commmand inside Source A and B. The Thread inside that is not working.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) It is likely the rest of the code statements are blocking the EDT.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: *most of the time* ... sounds like a threading issue to me. Consult the link that Andrew has mentioned

Comment: @Andrew the code is posted above. I tried using Thread just like what you've said, but still not working.

Comment: Note:  'the code'!='SSCCE'  Please (re)read the linked article.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ..needs to update the text (of the Label) everytime that task is done.

- you have issue with [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
- all updates to the Swing GUI must be done on EDT, even `Whatever.setText()` is declared as thread safe, but usage of `Thread.sleep(int)` from `Swing Listener` by default freeze Swing GUI and any changes aren't updated on the screen
- hack will be put  `taskLabel.setText(msg);` into `invokeLater()`, then output to the Swing GUI should be done on EDT
- see and to use `SwingWorker` as one of proper of ways, where methods `process`, `publish` and `done` notified EDT

Answer (score 0):

After you add the text to JLabel you should add that to the panel like this.
label.setText("something");
panel.add(label)

Comment: Speculation (that IMO is) best left to a comment at this stage.